# ErrorCollector with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

Is there a good way to see all errors collected by the ErrorCollector rule when running a unittest in Android Studio ?
I can only see the last error in the right pane of junit runner.The logcat tool shows the first error, but that's a lot less convenient to use than the unit test runner.

This is how I am currently using the ErrorCollector:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ClientTest {
    @Rule
    public final ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void example() {
        collector.addError(new Throwable("first thing went wrong"));
        collector.addError(new Throwable("second thing went wrong"));
    }
}
```

I would like to also see the first error in the right pane above the second error:
[image: Android Studio Junit Runner]

Comment: Did you find a way how to display all errors in the meantime? I did not find any configuration settings which would help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduced this issue on my environment - but it works as expected:

AnroidStudio 3.5
 
JUnit 4.12

[image]

Comment: interesting ! do you have a screenshot showing a bit more of the tool window ? i wonder if this is a configuration ?

Comment: I just started a new project